# Arabic letters in telegram commands

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot project with Python and i need to use commands such as /help or /start, but with Arabic letters such as /هلا, but it doesn't work with Arabic letters.

Image here:
[image: Telegram bot commands Image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. additionally, how specifically do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @ti7 
Thank you, I simply want to create a command on Telegram, such as /help or /start, but with Arabic letters such as /هلا, but it doesn't work with Arabic letters

Comment: You say you're using Python, but how we can help isn't clear - what do you have that _does_ work with non-Arabic characters? You can denote a `code block` using three back-tick marks ` to help format it nicely!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not supperted. See the [bot API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#botcommand).